# How the Shadow in Twitter for Mac when change tab is done?

Tags: objective-c, performance, macos, cocoa, calayer

When changing a tab in Twitter for mac , the old view slide to left, and the new view become center. both of old and new view has a shadow behind it.

I'v tried :

```
viewController.view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
viewController.view.layer.shadowRadius = 50.0;
viewController.view.layer.shadowColor = [TUIColor blackColor].CGColor;
viewController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4;
```

and used `viewController.view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;` trying to speed it up.

But still feel lag then twitter for mac.

What's the best performance way to add those shadow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at CALayer's shadowPath attribute. Typically if you are willing to tell the layer exactly how the shadow should be drawn then it will be faster than the default, where it tries to calculate a shadow based on the full view alpha channel.

For example:

```
    CGPathRef shadow = CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRectInset(self.bounds, -3, 1), NULL);
    [self.layer setShadowPath:shadow];
    [self.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5f] CGColor]];
    [self.layer setShadowOpacity:0];
    [self.layer setShadowRadius:8];
    CFRelease(shadow);
```

(this is iOS code but I believe the only thing you'll need to change is the UIColor reference).